# filter JSON not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to filter data from one JSON call using `http.get`?
Console says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Using Angular is easy doing one pipe service and finish, but using
ReactJS many things are complex.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function searchingData(product) {
  return function(x){
    return x.first.toLowerCase().includes(product.toLowerCase()) || !product;
  }
}

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items : [],
        product: ''
    };
    this.componentWillMount = this.componentWillMount.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then( data => this.setState({ items : data }) );
  }

  SearchWord(event) {
    this.setState({
      product: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {

    const {items, product} = this.state;

    return (
      <Router> 
        <div className="App">  

          {/* SHOW JSON */}

          <input type="text" placeholder="SEARCH DATA" onChange={this.componentWillMount} value="{product}" /> 

          <ul>
            {
              items.filter(searchingData(product)).map(item =>
                <li key={item.title}>
                    {item.title}
                </li>
            )}
          </ul>        

        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try this you are not calling inner function  `function searchingData(product) {
    return x.first.toLowerCase().includes(product.toLowerCase()) || !product;
}`

Comment: I think you should add an existence check this thing - x.first

Answer (score 0):

This should happen when your x or first is null

```
 return function(x){
    if(x && x.first != null){
    return x.first.toLowerCase().includes(product.toLowerCase()) || !product;
    }else
    return x;
  }
```

also no need to use quotes "" while binding

```
value={product}
```

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, using your snippet it works showing data.json, but show into input the value {product}. So I can't filter.

Comment: it should be value="product"

Comment: @Sajeetharan `product` is not a string. It should be value={product}

Comment: Please remove the double quote from your answer

Comment: I'm using value={product} so, but myy keyboard is locked. I can not write anything, why?, it's curiose friends.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      product: ""
    };
    this.SearchWord = this.SearchWord.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ items: data }));
  }

  SearchWord(event) {
    this.setState({
      product: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { items, product } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="SEARCH DATA"
          onChange={this.SearchWord}
          value={this.state.product}
        />

        <ul>
          {items.length &&
            items.filter(x => x.title.toLowerCase().includes(product.toLowerCase()))
            .map(item => <li key={item.title}>{item.title}</li>)
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/py17k2jnqm)

There are few issues in your code.

- You need to bind `SearchWord` method not `componentWillMount`
- input onChange should trigger `SearchWord` method
- input value should be `value={this.state.value}`
- In SearchData method you used `x.first`which should be `x.title`

Comment: Hi @nutboltu, using your snippet it works showing data.json, but show into input the value {product}. And I can't filter.

Comment: remove the doubleqoute ("). `value={product}`

Comment: I'm using value={product} so, but my keyboard is locked. I can not write anything, why?, it's curiose friends.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
            {
              this.state.map((item,key)=>
                <li key={item.title}>
                    {item.title}
                </li>
            )}
          </ul>
```

try this this and let me know 
and please provide me with your array to see how it is structured

Comment: `{
              items.length && items.filter(searchingData(product)).map(item =>
                <li key={item.title}>
                    {item.title}
                </li>
            )}`